# How to setup Phonegap Build with PushPlugin, Apigee on Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, apigee

I am trying to setup a Phonegap (v3.0.0) project with push notifications through Apigee and build the project using Phonegap Build using the command line interface.

Here is what I have so far:

1. I installed Phonegap on my Windows following these directions.
   http://phonegap.com/install/
2. I used the Phonegap command interface to create a project.
   http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface
3. I downloaded the Apigee Phonegap PushPlugin from Github and added the plugin to my project using the command line interface.
   https://github.com/apigee/appservices-phonegap-push-plugin
4. I followed the Apigee push notifications tutorial to setup Apigee and Google notification service.
   http://apigee.com/docs/usergrid/content/tutorial-push-notifications
5. This is where I get lost... I am trying to follow the Apigee phonegap android sample app but the tutorial file structure and the file structure of the current phonegap project is completely different.
   https://github.com/apigee/appservices-phonegap-android-push-example

Which files do I need to use from the Apigee demo app and where do I include them in my current phonegap project? I tried to follow the directions to configure the Apigee PushPlugin but during build Phonegap tells me the plugin is invalid and not supported.

Can someone help and offer me step by step instructions which files I should configure, copy and where in order to build the project using Phonegap Build and so the device sender id that is generated successfully gets sent to Apigee?

Thank you
PG

Answer (score 2):

The current Push notification plugin was made to be used with PhoneGap 2.6, so you will need the older version of PhoneGap for this to work. Once you are running 2.6, you should be able to get it running with the instructions in the readme.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Well I attempted to install v2.6.0 by downloading the zip from Phonegap but I am unable to install it using the command line interface. Is there a specific way to install the older version?